# Logstash and Grok filter failure

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

My log file has a single line (taken from the tutorial log file):

```
55.3.244.1 GET /index.html 15824 0.043
```

My conf file looks something like this:

```
input {
  file {
    path => "../http.log"
    type => "http"
  }
}

filter {
  grok {
    type => "http"
    match => [ "message", "%{IP:client}" ]
  }
}
```

I tested my grok filter with the grok debugger and it worked. I'm at a loss of what I am doing wrong. I get a [0] "_grokparsefailure" every time

Comment: I can't reproduce this with Logstash 1.4.2.

Comment: I am using logstash-1.1.12-flatjar.jar, let me try with latest the latest logstash. Are you saying this worked for you with 1.4.2?

Comment: Quick question - how do you run a conf file with logstash 1.4.2? Is it just bin/logstash -f file.conf?

Comment: Yes, it worked with 1.4.2. Yes, `bin/logstash -f file.conf` is fine. See the answer from @user3195649 though. That's what I thought you'd have to do before I discovered that what you had actually appears to work.

Comment: Don't use grok->type.  Put a conditional around the grok: if [type] == "http" { grok {} }

Answer (score 2):

As far as debugging a grok filter goes, you can use this link (http://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/) It has a very comprehensive pattern detector which is a good start.

If you only care about the IP and not the remainig part of the log message, following filter should work for you.

`%{IP:host} %{GREEDYDATA:remaining_data}`

The best method to debug is use, `stdin` and `stdout` plugins for logstash and debug your `grok` patterns.

You can find the documentation here `http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/`